# How to get values from a promise with node.js without .then function

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a problem with a promise using node.js. My code is below:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // my function here
});

p1.then(function(result){
  // my result
});
```

This code works but to get values from `p1` I must use the `.then` method and my result values can be accessed just on `p1.then`. How do I access `p1` values without `.then`?

Below are my expected results:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // my function here
    });

var abc = NextFunction(p1);
```

The `p1` values will be used afterwards in code outside of the `p1` variable.

Comment: You cannot. Everything you're doing without `then` would happen before the value is available.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context about the actual problem you are trying to solve or the goal you are trying to reach?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

p1 is a `Promise`, you have to wait for it to evaluate and use the values as are required by Promise.

You can read here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Although the `result` is available only inside the resolved function, you can extend it using a simple variable

```
var res;
p1.then(function(result){
    res = result; // Now you can use res everywhere
});
```

But be mindful to use `res` only after the promise resolved, if you depend on that value, call the next function from inside the `.then` like this:

```
var res;
p1.then(function(result){
    var abc = NextFunction(result);
});
```

Comment: if i have array outside .then, and push some element into array

why after out from p1.then this array still empty?

var myarray = [];

p1.then(function(result){
  myarray.push(result);
});

console.log(myarray); // still array empty

@AlexD

Comment: Because the item is only added when the promise is resolved. the line `p1.then(function(result){...})` just defines the callback function, so the next line would be your `console.log`. You should add to the array inside the function in `.then`. You can demonstrate it with a `setTimeout(function() { console.log(myarray); }, 5000);`

Comment: ah, yes...you right with using setTimeout my values on myarray can be access on outside p1, thanks @AlexD

Comment: This is very bad practice using timeout to wait for a promise to resolve,  so try to put relevant code in the .then

Comment: I cant make it working. http://jsfiddle.net/DAcWT/463/ I just want to get the actual value from the variable.

Answer (score 10):

You can use await after the promise is resolved or rejected.

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) { 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(x);
        }, 2000);
    });
}

async function f1() {
    var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
    console.log(x); // 10
}

f1();
```

Be aware `await` expression must be inside `async` function though.

Comment: but now your f1() needs an await...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, using the **deasync** module

```
var node = require("deasync");

// Wait for a promise without using the await
function wait(promise) {
    var done = 0;
    var result = null;
    promise.then(
        // on value
        function (value) {
            done = 1;
            result = value;
            return (value);
        },
        // on exception
        function (reason) {
            done = 1;
            throw reason;
        }
    );

    while (!done)
        node.runLoopOnce();

    return (result);
}

function test() {
    var task = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'Hello');
        //resolve('immediately');
    });

    console.log("wait ...");
    var result = wait(task);
    console.log("wait ...done", result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs 14.8.0+, you are able to use [top level awaits](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await).

So your script will now look like:

```js
var p1 = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // my function here
});

// p1 is now the result of the promise, not a promise
```

If you are doing this in the REPL, it is not enabled by default, so you have to run the REPL with the `--experimental-repl-await` flag. Using nvm, I was able to test even node version `12.20.1` and the repl flag works.

Comment: Node yells at me, saying I need to make my function async.  So now I have the same problem with the parent function.