# Node async axios

Tags: async-await

Help with Node and async problem.
In the first function, I am getting token from external api -

```
const Token = function getToken(data)
return axios(config)
.then((response) =>
this.response = response.data;
return this.response.access_token;)
.catch(function (error)
console.log(error);
);
```

Then, in the following function, I can output this token to the screen -

```
const myToken = Token(data);
myToken.then(function (result)
console.log(result); //here I see a real token
);
```

how then could I use this token?

```
Trying to do so -
const test = myToken;
console.log(test);
```

gives -  Promise pending

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get values from a promise with node.js without .then function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34392691/how-to-get-values-from-a-promise-with-node-js-without-then-function)

Comment: Thanks, Yegor. But didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Assign token value to variable in the outer scope inside `then`

```
let token = '';
myToken.then(function (result)
    token = result;
);
```

Comment: then console.log(token); token - is empty

Comment: do you mean axios(config)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` -

`const token = await myToken`

`await` will unpack the value of promise, similar to `.then()` but let's you use a more synchronous code style.

Note you'll also need to decorate the function that the above code lives within with the `async` keyword.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: const token = await myToken;
               ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: I already looked into this, but ...
Could you please give an example code for my case

Comment: I don't think you totally grasp promises. You can either use .then() or async/await. Your question suggests you are not wanting to put all your code in the `then` callback, so your other option is to use async + await. It's pretty simple, whatever function you have your `const token = await myToken` in you need to put `async` in front of `function`, i.e. `async function`. This now makes this function return a promise so you need to handle it as a promise whether it is being called, again with either `.then()` or async + await

Comment: "I don't think you fully understand the promises."
Yes, this is my first experience.
Could you please give an example code for my case.

Comment: I did in my answer and comments, I suggest you have a look at some of the online docs on js promises and difference between using `.then()` and using `async` + `await`. You'll be able to easily apply your learnings to your code.